# Facebook deep linking to company page in iOS 6 Web App

Tags: facebook, web-applications, ios6

I have a mobile Web app that uses links to my company's Facebook page, such as http://www.facebook.com/[My_Company].  This works fine when the link is clicked from a mobile browser -- Facebook loads in the browser directly to the "My_Company" Facebook page.

However, when adding my Web App to the Home Screen on iPhone running iOS 6, and then clicking the above link from my Web app, it simply launches the Facebook native app, with no "deep link" to the "My_Company" page (the Facebook native app loads to whatever page I had last visited while using the native app).

Is there a mechanism to deep link from a Web App that will load the Facebook native app to a specific page?  If not, is there a means to target the link to the browser instead of the native app (so that my company's page loads properly)?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Have any luck?

Comment: Still no luck, regrettably.

Answer (score 0):

You need the facebook pages ID and to open it with a URL like "fb://profile/385612258157212".

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.